# Netbeans custom syntax highlighter

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know if there is any tutorial on creating syntax highlighter for custom language in NetBeans?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're in luck! It looks like that question has been answered with an in-depth tutorial here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqSyntaxHighlight

It's a tutorial for a fictional language, but you should be able to follow through with your own custom language by following the principles it sets out.

Comment: I just want to highlight some keywords. Is there a simpler way to do it? Ideally, I should just have to specify a list of keywords.