# Editing vb.net in netbeans

Tags: vb.net, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

My work dropped a vb.net program in my lap that I need to modify.  Die vb.  Die.

Anyway, I work in Netbeans and can't find a module that will allow for syntax highlighting of vb.  Is there a creative solution out there for this that doesn't involve using a different IDE?

Thanks guys.

Comment: I personally don't know of any but is there any reason why you don't want to use the free Visual Studio Express?

Comment: I just didn't want to set up an entirely new IDE.  Also, to hell with Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400542/netbeans-custom-syntax-highlighter), there is a tutorial for setting up custom syntax highlighting in Netbeans [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SyntaxColoringANTLR) (direct link to tutorial instead of link to FAQ provided in linked question).

I think you might well find that it's less hassle to just install Visual Studio than to set up Netbeans to highlight VB.Net syntax, but that's up to you.  Good luck.

Comment: But I hate VS behavior... every IDE is different and Im sick from learning again and again different way to do same thing... it should be some norm to it...

Comment: Well, with JetBrains working on a C# IDE, it's entirely possible that in the future IntelliJ will be the single IDE you're looking for - it already supports an impressive list of languages.