# How can I enable netbeans function auto highlight option for php

Tags: php, netbeans

I am a new netbeans user so that I can't enable netbeans function, sting, variable heighlight option.

When I double click on a function it didn't height matching function, sting or others words.

I try to change it `tools-> options-> font and color` but vain. Please I will be happy if some help me about this issue.

[image]

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4400708/4153864

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans custom syntax highlighter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400542/netbeans-custom-syntax-highlighter)